# .addArgument is not a function Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Here is my Discord command module code, for some reason this is spitting out that .addArgument is not a function.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('purge')
    .setDescription('Purges a number of messages from the channel.')
    .addArgument('number', 'The number of messages to purge.')
    .addArgument('channel', 'The channel to purge messages from.')
    .setExecute(async (interaction, args) => {
        const channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === args.channel);
        if (!channel) return interaction.reply('Channel not found.');
        const messages = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: args.number });
        await channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        interaction.reply(`Purged ${messages.size} messages.`);
    }

);
```

It just gives me this:

> TypeError: (intermediate value).setName(...).setDescription(...).addArgument is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because there is nothing called `.addArgument()` in the `SlashCommandBuilder`. If you want to add arguments like numbers or channels, you need to use `.addNumberOption()` or `.addChannelOption()`. The way you will need to use to add a channel and number option is like this:

```js
.addNumberOption(option => {
    return option
        .setName('number') // Set the name of the argument here
        .setDescription('The number of messages to purge.') // Set the description of the argument here
        .setRequired() // This is optional. If you want the option to be filled, you can just pass in true inside the .setRequired() otherwise you can just remove it
})
.addChannelOption(option => {
    return option
        .setName('channel') 
        .setDescription('The channel to purge messages from.')
        .setRequired()
})
```

You can learn more about slash commands and options here => [Options | discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#options)

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I've been looking for.